# Separate UIViewController in same Storyboard

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

**Issue**

I have a single page app with a single view controller. On the screen there is a button that slides out/in a (smaller) UIView with a TableView (functions correctly). My goal is to simplify my view controller, hence my idea was to split off the UIView with the TableView into its own view controller. Therefore I've created a second view controller in the Storyboard and created a class HintsViewTableViewController, that contains the TableView datasource and delegate methods.

Main View controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    var HintsViewTableVC = HintsViewTableViewController()
```

HintsViewTableViewController

```
class HintsViewTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var HintsViewTableView: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet var hintsLabel: UILabel!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
       hintsLabel.text = "HINT"  <---fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while                                      unwrapping an Optional value
    }

// MARK: - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 4
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat (40)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel!.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    return cell 
    }
}
```

**Problem**
If the storyboard entry point is the Main View Controller, the compiler gives an error stating that my property hintsLabel! is nil and crashes.

If I move the storyboard entry point directly to the HintsViewTableViewController, then the app runs and shows the correct view on screen.

**Question**
Apparently, the procedure to initialize a view controller directly (using the storyboard entry point) is different from assigning the view controller to a variable (as I do in the first case). I've searched high and low for init methods, but have come up blank.

Another solution I've tried: making a separate XIB file and linking this to my HintsViewTableViewController, however TableViews in XIB files can't have prototype cells.

What am I missing here, or stated differently: what's the correct procedure to separate a UIView into a separate view controller (in the same Storyboard)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you instantiate your `HintsViewTableViewController` like this:

```
var HintsViewTableVC = HintsViewTableViewController()
```

you are creating an instance of the class, BUT that class knows nothing about your Storyboard, so all of the `@IBOutlet`s will be `nil` because they aren't wired to anything.

Instead, you need to ask the Storyboard to create the `ViewController`:

```
self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("hintsController") as! HintsViewTableViewController
```

where `hintsController` is the *Storyboard ID* you have set for that ViewController in the *Identity Inspector*.

Note:  You will need to make this call to the Storyboard in a method (such as `viewDidLoad` where `self` will refer to an instance of your `ViewController` class.

If you want to declare it as a property like you were doing before, making it a *lazy* property will allow it to be created when first accessed (and `self` will be available then):

```
lazy var hintsViewTableVC: HintsViewTableViewController = { self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("hintsController") as! HintsViewTableViewController }()
```

Comment: Thank you. I've changed this in my code. I have a function that animates the slide in and out of this view. However, now I can't seem to access this HintsViewTableVC in my animation function (part of the main view controller). Neither self.HintsViewTableVC nor HintsViewTableVC is found. Any pointers?

Comment: When you create the HintsViewTableVC, are you saving it to a property in your ViewController?  Is that how your animation function expects to access it.  You'll probably have to declare your property as `var hintsViewTableVC: HintsViewTableViewController?` since it is instantiated later.